# how to write get and post test methods for views in django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views, django-testing

I'm new to Django's testing and trying to write test functions for views, but I don't get the whole test view thing, I've seen a lot of examples but it seems to be to difficult, I need an example on something I wrote to get the idea.
here's a function I want to test its post and get:

```
    def ForgetPasswordRegistry(self, request):
    forgetpassword = True
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'UserID' in request.session:
            forgetpassword = False
        return request, forgetpassword
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        if self.IsUserExist(email):
            forget = models.ForgetPasswordRegistry()
            forget.UserID = self.GetUser(email)
            forget.Access = 1
            session = random.randint(999999999999999, 9999999999999999999999999999999999)
            forget.Session = str(session)
            link = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/resetpassword/' + forget.Session
            self.SendEmail('Reset-Password', link, [forget.UserID.Email])
            forget.save()
            FeedBack = ' Check Your Mail You Got A Recovery Mail'
            AlertType = 'alert-success'
            return request, AlertType, None, FeedBack, None, None
        else:
            AlertType = 'alert-danger'
            ModalFeedBack = 'This Email Dose Not Exist'
            EmailErrors = 'This Email Dose Not Exist'
            return request, AlertType, forgetpassword, None, EmailErrors, ModalFeedBack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let the concept of views confuse you!! Essentially there is a python function that you need to exercise certain conditionals of.

It looks like there are 4 main branches:

- GET not in session
- GET in session
- POST exists
- POST does not exist

so there should probably be at least 4 different tests.  I'll post the first one because it is pretty straightforward:

```
def ForgetPasswordRegistry(self, request):
forgetpassword = True
if request.method == 'GET':
    if 'UserID' in request.session:
        forgetpassword = False
    return request, forgetpassword

def test_forget_get_user_id_in_session(self):
    request = Mock(session={'UserID': 'here'}, method='GET')
    # instantiate your view class
    yourview = YourView()
    sefl.assertEqual(yourview.ForgetPasswordRegistry(request), (request, False))
```

The post user exists branch is a little more complicated because there are more things that the test needs to account for, and potentially provide stub implementations for:

- SendEmail
- GetUser
- models.ForgetPasswordRegistry()

Answer (score 1):

Use Django's test client: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client

Example:

```
from django.test import Client, TestCase


class ViewTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_post_creation(self):
        c = Client()  # instantiate the Django test client
        response = c.get('/forgetpassword/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status, 200)
```

Comment: this seems good but I want to check whether post and get are valid or invalid.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean, a status code of 200 means the HTTP response was valid. If there was anything else you want to check (like a text saying "Success"), you could check the body of the response (e.g. via `response.body`)

Comment: The TestCase has a attr `self.client`